# Экранирование в XML

Tags: android, android-xml

Столкнулся с тем, что не могу экранировать спецсимволы в `strings.xml`. В частности, `%`. Есть ли какая-то документация на этот счёт? Везде, где находил, про экранирование процента ни слова.

При вводе более одного знака `%` в `string-ресурсе` пишет:

```
Error:(724) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
```

Причём, это просто текст, не `String.format();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо удваивайте знак процента, либо используйте в теге `string` атрибут `formatted="false"`.

Comment: Спасибо! formatted="false" помогло.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ну Вы подождите, минута ещё :)